# how to print out values to the screen using flash ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a scaffold dum num:integer name:string
When I create a new dum, I wanted to use flash to print out the values of the number inputed into the form in the controller.

For example:

- User enter the webbrowser
- clicks create new dum
- then enters the num and name then press submit
- submit triggers the create call in the controller

  def create
      @dum = Dum.new(params[:dum])

  ```
  respond_to do |format|
    if @dum.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Dum was successfully created.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@dum) }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @dum, :status => :created, :location => @dum }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @dum.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
  ```

  end

Is there a way to print out the values in the flash function that is called to dispaly that the "Dum was sucesfully created".  I thought

```
 flash[:notice] = '#{@dum}'
```

would work, but it only prints out the #.

This is probably a really simple question to answer, but for some reason cannot figure it out.  Man purpose is to use this logic to debug with print statements of variables in the future.  Unless there is a better way to debug a web app please let me know.  In addition, how do you access the values grabbed from the form in here?

In the controller if i go:

@dum.num or @dum.name would that return me the input?

Thanks,
Any Advice appreciated.

Comment: I meant I haven't been able to print out the values from the controller onto the web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'#{@dum}'
^ Problem spotted
```

`'` != `"`. One does not interpolate, the other does.